# Finding median of a list of list of different length

Tags: python, list, median

here is my problem. I got a list of lists like this:

```
[
[1, 1, 1, 18, 35, 35, 70, 133, 280],
[1, 1, 1, 53, 90, 101, 130, 148, 178],
[1, 1, 1, 18, 35, 133, 133, 164],
[1, 1, 1, 18, 101, 108],
[1, 1, 18, 36, 86, 118, 126]
]
```

The list can have up to 9 items, and all the sublists contain at least 5 items.
I need to find the median for every number at the nth position per each list, ignoring lists too short (otherwise I would be out of index).

I tried `d = [item[i] for item in c]`, but it fails for i > 5 (when the lists start to have a different length). Any idea how to solve the problem?

The output for the solution in the example should be:

```
[median_numbers_1st_position, 
median_numbers_2nd_position,
median_numbers_3rd_position,
median_numbers_4th_position,
median_numbers_5th_position,
median_numbers_6th_position,
median_numbers_7th_position,
median_numbers_8th_position,
median_numbers_9th_position
]
```

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the "nth position" and "lists too short". What's your desired output? Please [edit] to clarify. And in the code you tried, what is `i` exactly? `for i in range(5)`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Did you mean you want the median of each "column" of your "ragged array"?

Comment: if you want to calculate medians of columns, you can do it with itertools zip_longest  and numpy ```[np.median(i) for i in [[k for k in j if k is not None] for j in itertools.zip_longest(*lst)]]``` output: ```[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 18.0, 86.0, 108.0, 128.0, 148.0, 229.0]```

Comment: I added info with a sample of the solution

Comment: @ianux22 see my comment above

Comment: It seems you do want the median of each column, but your edit doesn't clarify anything. At the very least, you could have calculated the medians and shown the actual expected output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without the overhead of *numpy* you could do this:

```
values = [
    [1, 1, 1, 18, 35, 35, 70, 133, 280],
    [1, 1, 1, 53, 90, 101, 130, 148, 178],
    [1, 1, 1, 18, 35, 133, 133, 164],
    [1, 1, 1, 18, 101, 108],
    [1, 1, 18, 36, 86, 118, 126]
]


def median(list_):
    m = len(list_) // 2
    list_ = sorted(list_) # to ensure compatibility with numpy.median
    if len(list_) % 2 == 0:
        return sum(list_[m-1:m+1]) / 2
    else:
        return float(list_[m])


for e in values:
    print(median(e))
```

**Output:**

```
35
90
26.5
9.5
36
```

Comment: assuming the input is sorted

Comment: @Nin17 Arithmetic Median is a positional average and refers to the middle value in a distribution. Therefore the median value has no bearing on whether (or not) the list is sorted

Comment: @AlbertWinestein I wouldn't be so sure about that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median#Finite_data_set_of_numbers for instance with ```[1,2,4,3,5]``` this gives ```4```

Comment: I inserted an output of the solution